# How to send BytesIO using requests post

Tags: python, python-requests, msgpack, bytesio

I am trying to send msgpack encoded values to server using requests post to an insert rest endpoint which takes the serialized byte stream as input. But it seems like the values are not getting there properly as I see no values getting inserted in the table. I have never tried this before, so please pardon my ignorance. Here's what I am doing:

```
buf = io.BytesIO()
for rows in dataframe:
    buf.write(msgpack.packb(rows))
    response = requests.post(url, data=buf, verify=False)
    try:
        response.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
        print('Error fetching response using requests')
```

Comment: if I'm not mistaken, the data needs to be an iterable for it to be streamed by requests.post. You might need to instead make a generator function writting to the buf and pass this generator to requests.post instead. the buf might not even be needed in this case.

Comment: buf.seek(0) is the way to do as the buf always points to the end of the buffer. And I also found out that I have to serialize every value instead of list of dicts which is why the insertion was failing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever I write to the buffer, the pointer will always point to the end of the buffer and waiting for a new write. So, when I pass `data=buf`, that is going to make an insertion with no values. The solution is to do `buf.seek(0)` and then pass `data=buf` as a parameter or simply `data=buf.seek(0)`

So, the following works:

```
for rows in dataframe:
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    buf.write(msgpack.packb(rows))
    buf.seek(0)
    response = requests.post(url, data=buf, verify=False)
    try:
        response.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
        print('Error fetching response using requests')
```

Answer (score 3):

extending your answer, using a with block is advised in-order to fix memory leak in case of exception.

```
for rows in dataframe:
    with io.BytesIO(msgpack.packb(rows)) as buf:
        buf.seek(0)
        response = requests.post(url, data=buf, verify=False)
    try:
        response.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
        print('Error fetching response using requests')
```

Comment: Pretty cool :) I like this. But do we still have to do seek in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can also add initial data when you create the `BytesIO` object so you don't have to call `seek`:

```
>>> import io
>>> buf = io.BytesIO(b"test")
>>> buf.tell()
0
>>> buf.read()
b'test'
>>> buf.tell()
4
```

Comment: aah. I see :)  So, I can simply do data=buf then :)